# Beginner question: how do I use the "move tool" in Gimp without moving the entire Layer?

Tags: typography, gimp, layers, text, kerning

I typed a short piece of text in GIMP, then I want to fix the kerning manually so I want to move the letters closer to each other. But when I select the "move" tool and click on the appropriate part of the image, I only seem to be able to move the entire layer. How do I select a certain part of the image and move it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Selecting Text Layers in Gimp

Text is represented in an own layer each until we decide to merge layers down. To quickly select a given Layer, or in this case text, I ususally open the *"Layers"* dialog, accessible from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or the *Windows > Dockable Dialogs* menu.

There we can select any layer to then use any available transform tool on it such as *Move*, *Scale*, *Transform*, etc.:

[image]

### Make a selection float

In case we need to transform or move a selection of an image we can choose *Select > Float* or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. The area selected will now float as a new layer over the background. This floating selection can also be transformed as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just realized though that this doesn't answer my question! I don't want to move the entire text box, just the individual letter. As in, I want to select an arbitrary rectangle in the image and move it around. How do I do this?

Comment: @Sid: see edit - is this what you need?